# Add X-Frame-Options for all urls on a web-site except a list of enabled

Tags: apache, iframe, web

We want to add `X-Frame-Options` to all Http responses except some of them (as some pages are supposed to be shown in iframes, and outside of the website). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with adding

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
....

<LocationMatch "....">
  Header unset X-Frame-Options
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Which server is this solution for? Apache?